# New tabs show "expand" on hover in Edge 25

Tags: bug, design, new-nav

In Edge 25, the new navigation tabs show "expand" upon hover for a few milliseconds before fading.

Other browsers (WebKit based, Firefox) do not show this behavior.

@AdrianoRepetti first noticed this.

[image: Tab hover showing unexpected expand]

Comment: The 2.0 nav no longer exists, as such this problem can no longer be reproduced, andI have votedto close in reflection of that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to edit their CSS, but I was just playing with the Inspector and came up with a potential solution:

In **all.css**, the `color` styling is causing the artifact:

```
#tabs a:hover, .tabs a:hover, .newnav .tabs-list-container .tabs-list .intellitab a:hover {
   color: #535a60; /* remove this */
   border-bottom-color: rgba(83, 90, 96, 0.5);
}

/* add this */
#tabs a:hover, .tabs a:hover, .newnav .tabs-list-container .tabs-list .intellitab a:hover .tab-name {
   color: #535a60;
}
```

The `color` property seems like it would be better applied to the `tab-name` class instead of the entire anchor tag and all of its children.